# QT creator doens't linking

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-construction, linker, qt-creator

I have a project with 2 subproject (Sub1 and Sub2):

```
ESI
|
|__Sub1
|
|__Sub2
```

In a implementation file (.cpp) of a class in the Sub2 (demo1.cpp) project i've the needs of include a class of the Sub1 project. So in the  demo1.cpp i've declared:

```
#include "../sub1/controller.h"
```

Why the linker doesn't find the constructor of the controller? (says undefined reference)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your `#include` tells the *Compiler* where it can find the *definition* of your `controller` class (i.e. the content of your `controller.h` file).

In order to link towards the *implementation* of your `controller` class, the linker requires a library which contains the already compiled implementation. - The `Sub2` project does not compile the contents of `Sub1` again, unless you include the `.cpp` files of `Sub1` in your `Sub2` project which would be bad practice and could lead to further problems, however.

---

Assuming `Sub1` is a library which will be generated as `sub1.lib`:

You need to add the following lines to your `.pro` file of your `Sub2` project:

```
LIBS += -L../Sub1 \
        -lsub1
```

This tells the linker that there is a "../Sub1" directory which contains libraries and that there is a library called "sub1.lib". The advantage of using the `-L` and `-l` syntax is that this works on all platforms (Windows, Linux, Mac, etc).

---

If both `Sub1` and `Sub2` are executables (i.e. the projects produce a `.exe`) file, you need to extract the common content into a separate project `Sub3` which has `TEMPLATE = lib` instead of `TEMPLATE = app` in its `.pro` file.